# MySQL : calculate SUM of a Query

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a mysql query that looks like this :

```
select  (pondérée_note*100)/pondérée as b 
from answers 
where answers.question_id in (select id 
                              from questions 
                              where categorie_id = 3) 
  and user_id = 5
```

The query returns a table b :

```
b
50
50
13
25
```

I want to do the sum of those values By

```
select SUM(query);
```

but it doesn't work because of a syntax error.

is it possible to sum a query like this ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select  sum((pondérée_note*100)/pondérée) as sumb 
from answers 
where answers.question_id in 
(select id from questions where categorie_id = 3) and user_id = 5
```